# asp.net - javascript better way to use onchange with multiple fields

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onchange

I have a asp.net web page which contains many textboxes.
If any of these boxes I run some javascript via the onchange event of each field.
The javascript basically changes a textbox to 'Y' so I know which section of the page has changed something.

Everything works fine, however I just need to know if there is a way of making the onchange call better/shorter ? Since I have over >100 textboxes, there is a lot of repetitive `onchange='CM('3');` on each and every textbox, so I am hoping there is a better way to handle this.

There are three divs, each containing some 35 textboxes, so perhaps there is a way of doing it by DIV, which I don't know.

Any guidance is appreciated.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDC1_D" runat="server" CssClass="STD_desc160"   onchange="CM('3');"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDC1_C" runat="server" CssClass="STD_cur30"     onchange="CM('3');"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDC1_1" runat="server" CssClass="STD_value55"   onchange="CM('3');"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDC1_2" runat="server" cssClass="STD_value55"   onchange="CM('3');"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDC1_3" runat="server" cssClass="STD_value55"   onchange="CM('3');"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDC1_B" runat="server" CssClass="STD_bassis"    onchange="CM('3');"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDC2_D" runat="server" CssClass="STD_desc160"   onchange="CM('2');"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDC2_C" runat="server" CssClass="STD_cur30"     onchange="CM('2');"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDC2_1" runat="server" CssClass="STD_value55"   onchange="CM('2');" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDC2_2" runat="server" cssClass="STD_value55"   onchange="CM('2');" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDC2_3" runat="server" cssClass="STD_value55"   onchange="CM('2');" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDC2_B" runat="server" CssClass="STD_bassis"    onchange="CM('2');"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
```

Comment: is  jQuery also an option ?

Comment: for the moment I would prefer not to use jQuery, but if there is no other choice I will.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is also an option ( which I strongly recommend) , so :

```
$(function (){

    $("input[type=text]").on('change',function (){
     if ($(this).val()) $(this).val('Y'); else $(this).val('');
    })
});
```

if not , I will delete this answer.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but how would I get rid of the many onchange="CM('2'); calls I do on each textbox of the aspx page ?